# Getting different answers by different methods for angle made by a pendulum moving with constant acceleration

Tags: forces, classical-mechanics, work

A point mass $m$ is hanging by a string of length $l$ in a car moving with a constant acceleration $a$. Using car frame and pseudo force, we easily get that the angle made by string with vertical is :

$$\theta = \arctan(\frac{a}{g})$$

However when I solve it using work-energy theorem , I'm getting that :

$$\theta = 2\arctan(\frac{a}{g})$$

Here's how I did it : When the mass $m$ will finally make an angle $\theta$ which we need to find, it's velocity will be zero ( working from car frame). So change in kinetic energy is zero. Hence, sum of work done by each forces is zero so that :

$$W_g+ W_T+ W_f=0$$

$W_g$ is work done by gravity which is $-mgl(1-\cos(\theta))$.

$W_T$ is work done by tension which is zero because tension force was always perpendicular to displacement vector at any instant.

$W_f$ is work done by pseudo force which is equal to $mal\sin(\theta)$.

Hence , by work energy theorem :

$$mal\sin(\theta)=mgl(1-\cos(\theta)$$

Which gives ,

$$\theta = 2\arctan(\frac{a}{g})$$

Here's a diagram to help visualise the situation :

[image]

Note that vertical displacement is $l(1-\cos\theta)$ and $ma$ is pseudo force.

Please explain in simple language what wrong is going here.
Thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By your second way you do not get the equilibrium position, but the maximum angle you get when you accelerate the car. the pendulum goes to the double angle and than drops back, without friction it never reaches equilibrium.

Comment: So you're saying that pendulum will never reach equilibrium in this case. Clearly it does , exactly when it reaches angle arctan ( a/g) because net force becomes zero.

Comment: No, if you  have a normal pendulum with equilibrium in the middle, if you push it once it will move all the time it goes to equilibrium only by friction, which you neglected . same with an accelerating car  the pendulum goes beyond equilibrium point. when it reaches equilibrium point, you are right, force is zero, but it still has velocity or kinetic energy, like you proved by the way with your calculation.

Comment: So the pendulum will never be at rest even according to car frame ? But my book question says that to find the angle at which it gets finally hanged at.

Comment: in reality you have friction in your car, as outside, so after some time you reach equilibrium same with the pendulum you pushed, and then it stays that way, since there is no force. Thats why you have to calculate the point of zero force .

Comment: Okay thanks. I get it.